# JQuery 1.11 not loading from manifest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I just started playing with Chrome extensions, trying to load JQuery from manifest file, and test if it's loaded. It is not loading, although I did specify it in content-scripts! Any idea why?

**sample.js**

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "__MSG_extName__",
    "version": "0.1",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "background": { "scripts": ["sample.js"] },
    "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
    "minimum_chrome_version": "33",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "js": ["lib/jquery-1.11.0.js"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: You are injecting jQuery as a content script, but looking for it in the background page, those are 2 different places.

Comment: OK. I am confused where to link to JQ from: I want it to load it once (per extension load), but I want to be able to use it on every page web page. Should I load it in "background" together with my sample.js?

Comment: You will need to load it everywhere you need it.

Answer (score 0):

To inject jQuery to every page you can do use this approach.

Add the following line to the *manifest.json* file. This specify that packaged resource (jQuery file inside extension) is expected to be usable in the context of a web page.

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["lib/jquery-1.11.0.js"]
```

Add the following code into new file located in your (file *manifest.json*) `"content_scripts: [{ "js": new_file.js }]"` to actually inject jQuery when `onLoad` event triggers:

The *new_file.js* file:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('lib/jquery-1.11.0.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
};
```

Comment: If I point to my JQ library from content-scripts, will the library be loading over and over again on each page load?

Comment: Yes, it will be loaded for every webpage.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments to the question, you are doing things in two different contexts.

The `"background"` key defines what is loaded in a single invisible page where the "main" code resides.
`"content_scripts"` injects code into other pages instead, that can communicate with the background page via Chrome API.

A good overview is available [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#contentScripts).

It's not immediately clear why `<all_urls>` match pattern does not inject the script into your background page, but fact is, it's not.

How to modify your example depends on what you try to achieve.

- If you need `sample.js` to be executed on every page when it loads, you need to move it to the `"content_scripts"` key. Note that most of the Chrome API will be unavailable.
- If you also need jQuery in your background page (doubtful, but possible), you can add it to the `background.scripts` list.
- If you need some processing done that is not available to the content scripts, then you need to have two scripts, one background script that does the work and an injected content script that communicates with it via [Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).